# What is a good word to describe a poem that always seems new and relevant?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a good word to describe a poem which always seems new and relevant (despite the passage of time)?

For example, "William Shakespeare's .......... sonnets are still popular today."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call them ***[timeless](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/timeless)***:

> 1a : not restricted to a particular time or date
>    *// the timeless themes of love, solitude, joy, and nature — Writer*
>   <sub>*definition from [merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/timeless)*</sub>

Answer (score 3):

This fits the definition of (an) *evergreen*, a word which can be used both as an adjective and a noun:

> 2a : retaining freshness or interest
>     b : universally and continually relevant
>        : not limited in applicability to a particular event or date

> 3 : something that retains its freshness, interest, or popularity

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evergreen))</sub>